# How to learn Drools well?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, expert-system, drools-planner, kie-workbench

I am student and new to learn Drools. I am confused about how to learn the Drools. I know nothing about this area but my professor let me learn this things and make an expert system.

I have installed the drools workbench -- kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.4.0.Final-tomcat7 this version. But I don't know how to learn it well.  That means next step and next next step. What I need to do? Would you tell me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I need install another things? Or just drools workbench?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of demo applications available on github, you can refer to them and also there is drools documentation you can refer to.

Comment: I am reading the Drools documentation now. Thank you very much. In Drools Workbench, when using the "Guild Rule", does it possible to add a new set of WHEN and THEN?

Comment: No. If you want to use multiple set of WHEN and THEN you have to DRL rule format.

Comment: If so, doesn't Drools Workbench suitable for non-programmers?

Comment: DRL rule format is for developers. If you want non-technical user tobe able to write rules then you can try with spreadsheet rules. In spreadsheet rule format developer can set all the columns and enduser will just add rows based on requirement.

Comment: Really thank you very much. I will try to use spreadsheet rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to learn the Drools language you should use Eclipse/Idea and check out the code examples Drools releases deliver. The Drools documentation describes few of them and walks you through them. Once you can run them in your IDE start changing parts from here and there to see how the run results change.

The workbench offers a lot of tools for authoring rules in different formats: with plain DRL that is the Drools language and with different guided editors that hide the actual Drools syntax and give you a more visual editor for rule authoring.

The workbench also gives you tools for releasing and managing released rule projects, but it is hard to learn the actual language since there is no good way to run the rules in the workbench. You need to either use Test Scenarios to run the rules or build a kjar out of your project and then use it in an application that you would have to write yourself.

Best to start with an IDE and just use the premade examples.